# For looping struct members with a pointer to a struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct, arduino, function-pointers

I think my pointer game is rusty, I can't seem to get the for loop implementation to work. It's like the pointer isn't incremented along with the array. 
Any suggestions?

I implemented a "manual" version of what i want the loop to do. It worked as expected.

```
typedef struct txstruct_t
{
    uint8_t tx[8];
    void(*send)(struct txstruct_t *cthis, uint8_t arr[8]);

}txstruct_t;

void send(txstruct_t *cthis, uint8_t arr[8]);


void loop() 
{
    txstruct_t txobj;
    uint8_t buf[8] = { 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0 };
    send(&txobj, buf);

}

// This works
void send(txstruct_t *cthis, uint8_t arr[8])
{
    cthis->tx[0] = arr[0];
    cthis->tx[1] = arr[1];
    cthis->tx[2] = arr[2];
    cthis->tx[3] = arr[3];
    cthis->tx[4] = arr[4];
    cthis->tx[5] = arr[5];
    cthis->tx[6] = arr[6];
    cthis->tx[7] = arr[7];

    return;
};

/*
//This doesn't work :(
void send(txstruct_t *cthis, uint8_t arr[8])
{

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        cthis = cthis + i;
        cthis->tx[i] = arr[i];
    }

    return;
};*/
```

I would love some clarification on this, so I could learn how to avoid this in the future! Maybe even a better method of implementing such buffers.

Comment: Where is this logic `cthis + i` (where `i` > 0) supposed to point to when you pass `&txobj`?

Comment: If you want to try pointer arithmetic you could do `uint8_t dataptr = cthis->tx; for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) { *(dataptr++) = arr[i]; }`. BTW: I suggest to replace the magic number `8`with a `#define` or `enum` value in `txstruct_t` and use `sizeof(cthis->tx)` to limit the loop in your `send` function.

Comment: Yes thank you @Bodo of course. This was merely a quick and dirty test :)
But you are absolutely right!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cthis = cthis + i;` can be removed. It makes no sense at all as it's an undefined attempt to somehow reset the pointer to the `struct`. You don't do that in the *unrolled* version of the loop, do you?

The other components of the loop are fine.

Comment: I added the cthis = cthis + i; in a desperate attempt of foolishness. since it didn't work as intended. 
It works now .. Don't know what I did .. Classic..